# Sticky Header with fading out image

Tags: jquery, css, header

I have following jsfiddle.
Header, that gets smaller when scrolling down ("sticky header").
I have a png overlay that also gets smaller with it. How can I animate it that it doesn't look as it does now (bad)?
I searched for fadeIn with jQuery but still doesn't work.

So how can I shrink the header while fading out the image? Thanks

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50){  
        $('#header').addClass("sticky");
        $('#logo').addClass("sticky");

    }
    else{
        $('#header').removeClass("sticky");
        $('#logo').removeClass("sticky");

    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n5upsekf/

Comment: fadeOut(1500).removeClass("sticky"); obviously doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

it's correct

```html
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50){  
        $('#logo, #header').fadeIn(1500);
        $('#header, #logo').addClass("sticky");

    }
    else{
        $('#logo, #header').fadeOut(1500);
        $('#header, #logo').removeClass("sticky");

    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, it fades the content out completely